# how can I prevent access to group policy

Tags: windows, security

how can I prevent access to group policy from all users except the administrator one so no one can change the group policy except the specified one

Comment: Are you talking about domain group policies or local group policies?

Comment: @LPChip local group policy

Comment: Don't let people have local administrative permissions.

Comment: @Seth please can you give me more details ?

Comment: Is there a domain involved?

Comment: no and user is member of gust as explained here https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001097.htm  but still can access `gpedit`

Comment: That article explains how to grant administrator permissions to a user. If he does have those permissions he will be able to change GP settings. Also it's targeted for Windows XP. Are you running Windows XP or something more current?

Comment: Yes you are right so i did same steps but instead if givening permission i revoked them  and yes i am. Working on windows xp thank you for your help